# Как отличить ssd от hdd?

Tags: windows, hdd, ноутбук, ssd

Есть ноутбук. Как не разбирая его узнать, что в нём установлено - ssd или hdd?

Comment: Название модели в диспетчере устройств посмотреть?

Comment: Послушать, если не шумит с пощёлкиванием, значит ssd.

Comment: Тебе програмно или глазами узнать?

Comment: Ну вообще глазами. Но программно тоже любопытно теперь :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нажимаешь пуск в строке поиска пишешь > оптимизация дисков . твердотельный накопитель это ssd - жёсткий диск - это hdd

Comment: Программа для дефрагментации - неожиданно, но работает :)

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, MS пришлось научить ее отличать ssd. В Win 7 такое еще не работало, только по имени смотреть или специально обученным софтом.

Answer (score 3):

пуск> правой кнопкой мыши по компьютеру> свойства > диспетчер устройств > дискове устройства и в яндексе модель вводишь

Comment: А без яндекса никак?